# Selecting integers which are not a member in an ordered list of integers

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, integer-sequence

I have an ordered list of integers, i.e.:

```
list = {1,3,5,6,8,10,12,15};
```

and I want to know if there is a fast way to get a list of the integers that do not appear in this list. 
The best thing I've come up with is

```
list2 = Select[Range[Nd], FreeQ[list,#]&];
```

which for this particular case yields

```
{2, 4, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14}
```

but I suspect there is a faster, more efficient way.

Comment: If `Nd >= Last[list]` then `list2 = Range[Nd]; list2[[list]] = Nothing;` will do

Comment: Thanks for the accept but it is a good habit to hold on a day or two to not discourage others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be faster and scales better, depends on sparsity of `list` I guess:

```
Complement[Range[Last[#]], #] &@list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list // Pick[Range[Last@#], SparseArray[# -> #], 0] &
```

> {2, 4, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14}

Or:

```
list // Range[Last@#] /. Thread[# -> Nothing] &
```

> {2, 4, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14}